# iPhone Messages vs. iPad Messages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, messages, ipados

On my iPhone, I can put the cursor in the middle of a word in Messages to change spelling, mistakes.  The little magnification bubble appears, which also helps.  Neither my iPad 10.5 nor my wife's iPad Air 2 can do that.  We have to settle for the cursor appearing at the end of the word, and backspacing to erase the word to re-enter it.

Can we tell iPad messages to act like the iPhone on Messages?

Comment: What versions of iOS do you have on your iPhone and iPads?  You can get that info from Settings → General → About.

Comment: iPad Pro 10.5, iOS 13.3.1
iPhone 10.3.3 model number MG5W2LL/A (iPhone 6 I think)